# grep to search for a specified pattern

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, grep

i want to grep all the texts in a file which contain symbols (non alpha numeric) and start with a number and which have spaces between them

```
grep -i "^[0-9]\|[^a-zA-Z0-9]\| "
```

I have written the following grep command which works perfectly , however i also wish to include those texts which are not in a particular limit say for example all those texts which are less than 3 and more than 15 should be greped
How can include that limit pattern as well in one command

I tried using

```
{3,15}
```

and all but could not get the desired output

```
sample input 
aa
9dsa
abcd
abc#$
ab d

Sample output
aa               //because length less than 3
ab d             //because has space in between
9dsa             // because starts with a number
abc#$            //because has special symbols in it
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: What do you mean by `contain symbols`? As in non alpha numeric?

Comment: @Cyrus done !! i have added 'em

Comment: It does not help, if you say `etc`, since we wouldn't know what that can include. I will post an answer assuming no `etc`

Comment: @Vikhram non alpha numeric as u said to be precise !!

Comment: Your question says *and* but in your regex you are saying *or* (`\|`). There is no simple, straightforward way to *and* regular expressions (I've seen a few demos where `&` was added to regex syntax but it turned out to be more confusing than helpful) - I'd go with the Awk answer (with `||` suitably replaced with `&&`) if that's what you want.

Comment: @tripleee it's a common mistake people make when describing their requirements - instead of saying `I want to print lines containing foo and I want to print lines containing bar` (which would be implemented as `grep 'foo|bar'`) they attempt to abbreviate it and end up saying `I want to print lines containing foo and bar` (which means something completely different and would be implemented as `grep 'foo.*bar|bar.*foo'`) instead of what they really meant: `I want to print lines containing foo or bar`. Luckily the example tells us what the OP really wants.

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah, I'm mainly hoping the OP would [edit] the question to fix this ambiguity.

Comment: Me too and I'm hoping both our comments help them understand what's wrong with it ;-)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity, simplicty, robustness, portability, etc. just use awk instead of grep to search for non-trivial conditions:

```
$ awk 'length()<3 || length()>15 || /[^[:alnum:]]/ || /[[:space:]]/ || /^[0-9]/' file
aa
9dsa
abc#$
ab d
```

I mean seriously, that couldn't get much clearer/simpler and it will work in any POSIX awk and it's trivial to change if/when your requirements change.

Answer (score 1):

Below expression should help you find the required lines. I am assuming you will use `grep -E` so the alternation will work properly

```
^[[:digit:]]|[@#$%^&*()]|^.{0,3}$|^.{15,}$
```

Below is the explanation for the regex

```
^[[:digit:]]    - Match a line that starts with a number
[@#$%^&*()]     - Match a line containing the specified symbols.
                  Alternatively you can use [^[:alnum:]], if you want 
                  the symbol to match any non alpha numeric character. 
                  Beware that a space, underscore, tab, quote, etc are all 
                  examples of non alpha numeric characters
^.{0,3}$        - Match a line containing less than 3 characters
^.{15,}$        - Match a line containing more than 15 characters
```

Comment: You'll need GNU awk for `\d`. Don't try to list non-alphanumeric characters (you're missing many!), just negate the POSIX character class `[:alnum:]`.